# Static IP settings not getting saved on Windows 2012 R2 aws ec2

Tags: windows, networking, static-ip

I am having AWS ec2 windows 2012 R2 instance. I want to assign 3 private IPs to it. I assigned them into AWS console. Now when I tried to set it on the actual server, from Network adapter settings first time it got saved. When I did `ipconfig /all` it showed all the IPs.

When after applying the updates I restarted the server and then checked again for IPs, then out of 3 address one IP was not present with `ipconfig /all` command. When I saw in the GUI i.e. Network Adapter -> properties -> Advanced, it was present there. So I deleted that entry and added again and clicked OK. But this change was not reflected in `ipconfig /all` command.

Furthermore when I deleted the IP from the GUI and opened back the GUI again that IP was still present there.

In short, the extra static IP I set is not getting saved and also not getting reflected in `ipconfig` command. Any idea?